# How to connect container stdin & stdout with websocket?

Tags: go, containers, stdout, stdin

At present I want to connect container stdin and stdout with websocket.  But I can not read stdout if there are no output. e.g. "cd /"

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    dcl "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "context"
    "html/template"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "flag"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "bufio"
)

var inout chan []byte
var output chan []byte

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    cli, err := dcl.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    execConfig := types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStderr: true,
        AttachStdin:  true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        Cmd:          []string{"/bin/sh"},
        Tty:          false,
        Detach:       false,
    }

    //set target container
    exec, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, "ubuntu", execConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    execAttachConfig := types.ExecStartCheck{
        Detach: false,
        Tty:    false,
    }
    containerConn, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, exec.ID, execAttachConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    defer containerConn.Close()

    bufin := bufio.NewReader(containerConn.Reader)

    go func(w io.WriteCloser) {
        for {
            data, ok := <-inout
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("!ok")
                w.Close()
                return
            }

            fmt.Println(string(data))
            w.Write(append(data, '\n'))
        }
    }(containerConn.Conn)

    go func() {
        for {
            buffer := make([]byte, 4096, 4096)
            c, err := bufin.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil{
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            //c, err := containerConn.Reader.Read(buffer)
            if c > 0 {
                output <- buffer[:c]
            }
            if c == 0{
                output <- []byte{' '}
            }
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    for {

        mt, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        }

        log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        inout <- message
        data := <-output
        err = conn.WriteMessage(mt, data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            break
        }
    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTemplate.Execute(w, "ws://"+r.Host+"/echo")
}

func main() {

    inout = make(chan []byte)
    output = make(chan []byte)

    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
}

var homeTemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var ws;
    var print = function(message) {
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.innerHTML = message;
        output.appendChild(d);
    };
    document.getElementById("open").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");
        ws.onopen = function(evt) {
            print("OPEN");
        }
        ws.onclose = function(evt) {
            print("CLOSE");
            ws = null;
        }
        ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            print("RESPONSE: " + evt.data);
        }
        ws.onerror = function(evt) {
            print("ERROR: " + evt.data);
        }
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("send").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        print("SEND: " + input.value);
        ws.send(input.value);
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws.close();
        return false;
    };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td valign="top" width="50%">
<p>Click "Open" to create a connection to the server,
"Send" to send a message to the server and "Close" to close the connection.
You can change the message and send multiple times.
<p>
<form>
<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
<p><input id="input" type="text" value="ls">
<button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
</td><td valign="top" width="50%">
<div id="output"></div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
`))
```

I try many ways, but no way can work :(

Comment: You are basically doing a websocket version of ssh. Maybe you can search for that.

Comment: The [gorilla command example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/command) might be useful to you.  Replace the os/exec calls with docker client calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the timeout on the call because in this part:

```
log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
    inout <- message
    data := <-output
    err = conn.WriteMessage(mt, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("write:", err)
        break
    }
```

You are waiting always to get the response for the server.

Here are you code working properly with the timeout implemented and an issue on the socket because needs to send utf8 and needs to be parsed to utf8 before send to the client.

```
package main

import (
    dcl "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "context"
    "html/template"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "flag"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

var inout chan []byte
var output chan []byte

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    cli, err := dcl.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    execConfig := types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStderr: true,
        AttachStdin:  true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        Cmd:          []string{"/bin/sh"},
        Tty:          false,
        Detach:       false,
    }

    //set target container
    exec, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, "vigorous_mclean", execConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    execAttachConfig := types.ExecStartCheck{
        Detach: false,
        Tty:    false,
    }
    containerConn, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, exec.ID, execAttachConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    defer containerConn.Close()

    bufin := bufio.NewReader(containerConn.Reader)

    // Write to docker container
    go func(w io.WriteCloser) {
        for {
            data, ok := <-inout
            log.Println("Received to send to docker", data)
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("!ok")
                w.Close()
                return
            }

            w.Write(append(data, '\n'))
        }
    }(containerConn.Conn)

    // Received of Container Docker
    go func() {
        for {
            buffer := make([]byte, 4096, 4096)
            c, err := bufin.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            //c, err := containerConn.Reader.Read(buffer)
            if c > 0 {
                output <- buffer[:c]
            }
            if c == 0 {
                output <- []byte{' '}
            }
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        conn.CloseHandler()
        mt, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        log.Println(mt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        } else {
            log.Printf("recv: %s\n", message)
            inout <- message
            select {
            case data := <-output:
                stringData := string(data[:])
                if !utf8.ValidString(stringData) {
                    v := make([]rune, 0, len(stringData))
                    for i, r := range stringData {
                        if r == utf8.RuneError {
                            _, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(stringData[i:])
                            if size == 1 {
                                continue
                            }
                        }
                        v = append(v, r)
                    }
                    stringData = string(v)
                }
                err = conn.WriteMessage(mt, []byte(stringData))
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println("write:", err)
                }

            case <-time.After(time.Second * 1):
                log.Println("Timeout")

            }
        }

    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTemplate.Execute(w, "ws://"+r.Host+"/echo")
}

func main() {

    inout = make(chan []byte)
    output = make(chan []byte)

    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
}

var homeTemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var ws;
    var print = function(message) {
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.innerHTML = message;
        output.appendChild(d);
    };
    document.getElementById("open").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");
        ws.onopen = function(evt) {
            print("OPEN");
        }
        ws.onclose = function(evt) {
            print("CLOSE");
            ws = null;
        }
        ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            print("RESPONSE: " + evt.data);
        }
        ws.onerror = function(evt) {
            print("ERROR: " + evt.data);
        }
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("send").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        print("SEND: " + input.value);
        ws.send(input.value);
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws.close();
        return false;
    };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td valign="top" width="50%">
<p>Click "Open" to create a connection to the server,
"Send" to send a message to the server and "Close" to close the connection.
You can change the message and send multiple times.
<p>
<form>
<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
<p><input id="input" type="text" value="ls">
<button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
</td><td valign="top" width="50%">
<div id="output"></div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
`))
```

Another method to connect directly the stdout to websocket without any timeout is create a goroutine that when you receive something from the docker send to the client directly and the code can be this

```
package main

import (
    dcl "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "context"
    "html/template"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "flag"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "bufio"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

var inout chan []byte
var output chan []byte

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8080", "http service address")

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    cli, err := dcl.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }

    ctx := context.Background()
    execConfig := types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStderr: true,
        AttachStdin:  true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        Cmd:          []string{"/bin/sh"},
        Tty:          false,
        Detach:       false,
    }

    //set target container
    exec, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, "sharp_goldwasser", execConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    execAttachConfig := types.ExecStartCheck{
        Detach: false,
        Tty:    false,
    }
    containerConn, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, exec.ID, execAttachConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(err.Error()))
        return
    }
    defer containerConn.Close()

    bufin := bufio.NewReader(containerConn.Reader)

    // Write to docker container
    go func(w io.WriteCloser) {
        for {
            data, ok := <-inout
            log.Println("Received to send to docker", data)
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("!ok")
                w.Close()
                return
            }

            w.Write(append(data, '\n'))
        }
    }(containerConn.Conn)

    // Received of Container Docker
    go func() {
        for {
            buffer := make([]byte, 4096, 4096)
            c, err := bufin.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            //c, err := containerConn.Reader.Read(buffer)
            if c > 0 {
                output <- buffer[:c]
            }
            if c == 0 {
                output <- []byte{' '}
            }
            if err != nil {
                break
            }
        }
    }()
    // Connect the STDOUT to the Socket
    go func () {
        data := <-output
        stringData := string(data[:])
        if !utf8.ValidString(stringData) {
            v := make([]rune, 0, len(stringData))
            for i, r := range stringData {
                if r == utf8.RuneError {
                    _, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(stringData[i:])
                    if size == 1 {
                        continue
                    }
                }
                v = append(v, r)
            }
            stringData = string(v)
        }
        err = conn.WriteMessage(1, []byte(stringData))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
        }
    }()

    for {
        conn.CloseHandler()
        _, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("read:", err)
            break
        } else {
            log.Printf("recv: %s\n", message)
            inout <- message

        }

    }
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTemplate.Execute(w, "ws://"+r.Host+"/echo")
}

func main() {

    inout = make(chan []byte)
    output = make(chan []byte)

    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
}

var homeTemplate = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var ws;
    var print = function(message) {
        var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.innerHTML = message;
        output.appendChild(d);
    };
    document.getElementById("open").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws = new WebSocket("{{.}}");
        ws.onopen = function(evt) {
            print("OPEN");
        }
        ws.onclose = function(evt) {
            print("CLOSE");
            ws = null;
        }
        ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            print("RESPONSE: " + evt.data);
        }
        ws.onerror = function(evt) {
            print("ERROR: " + evt.data);
        }
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("send").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        print("SEND: " + input.value);
        ws.send(input.value);
        return false;
    };
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(evt) {
        if (!ws) {
            return false;
        }
        ws.close();
        return false;
    };
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td valign="top" width="50%">
<p>Click "Open" to create a connection to the server,
"Send" to send a message to the server and "Close" to close the connection.
You can change the message and send multiple times.
<p>
<form>
<button id="open">Open</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
<p><input id="input" type="text" value="ls">
<button id="send">Send</button>
</form>
</td><td valign="top" width="50%">
<div id="output"></div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
`))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not my expect behavior.  I want to get the command's stdout, if there has a timeout, I don't have chance to get output. Maybe I need research websocket version of ssh

Comment: For do that I recommend to change the websocket for another library because you need to send the message type and you can't predefine the message types. I modified the code to connect the stdout to the websocket directly like the ssh does.

Comment: Still not work. :-(  I try to find another library.  I don't know docker how to solve it. If have time, I will research docker code to find a way.  Tks  Adrián Polo Alcaide

Comment: O. Line 167 lost a for loop. I add this for loop, but still cannot get stdout like "cd /".  If I type "cd /" in the web, still block in the "data := <-output". :-(

Comment: If you copy the second code on the answer will work fine. The "cd /" command not have any stdout. You need to create a gorutine to connect the stdout to the websocket.